# Unit test in Angular 2+ (testing method call on button click)

Tags: angular

I am trying to test method call when certain button is clicked, nothing seems to work.

This is the line in my HTML file:

```
<button class="btn-grey" (click)="methodTest()">ODUSTANI</button>
```

And method in my component:

```
export class MyComponent {

    constructor (public dialog: Matdialog) {}

    methodTest(): void {
        this.dialog.open(
            myOtherComponent,
            {disableClose: true, data:{title: someTitle, message: someMessage}
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Please give the full code

Comment: I edited the original question. This is information I can provide.

Comment: Is there any error message on the console? Maybe you missed a `}` in your method.

Comment: The question is not about the method, it works just fine. I am trying to write unit test for that method call on click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up the test using the Angular TestBed and inject the service.

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let component: TestComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [
         AppModule
       ],
       declarations: [ 
       ],
       providers: [
       ]}).compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
         comp = fixture.componentInstance;
      });
   }));
});
```

Then you need to spy on the onButtonClick method, click the button and check that whether the method was called

```
it('should', async(() => {
   spyOn(component, 'onButtonClick');

   let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
   button.click();

   fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
   expect(component.onButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
}));
```

Comment: that's verifying that the button is clicked on.